# Once I have installed a program on Ubuntu, how do I run it?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gnome

I have just [installed mongodb using apt-get](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages). Now, unlike some other programs, it has not appeared in the applications drop down (I am using GNOME and Ubuntu 10.04).

Also: Apologies for the simplicity of this question. I have *just* moved from using Windows and am just a bit confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB is not an application but a *service* – it does not have a graphical interface by itself. It is used only through other applications, for storing and retrieving data; most commonly by web sites (diaspora*, Craigslist, for example).

When writing a program yourself, you would use a "driver" to connect to the database from whichever language you use. For example, in Python (interactive mode):

```
$ python
>>> import pymongo
>>> connection = pymongo.Connection("localhost")
>>> db = connection.testdatabase
```

There *are* applications for browsing the entire MongoDB contents; most of them are listed in the [Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) page at MongoDB website.